# How to install Keil Uvision in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

How to install Keil Uvision in Ubuntu 14.04 without WINE.

Here is the link of the software http://www2.keil.com/mdk5/uvision/

Comment: On their [System Requirement page](http://www2.keil.com/system-requirements/) there is no port for Linux, only Windows.  You cannot install it in Linux without wine or running a VM with Windows in it.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're referring to this tool http://www2.keil.com/mdk5/uvision/, this cannot be installed in Linux natively without Wine. Because the tool is for Windows Only. I'm even not sure if it will work with Wine, but that is another issue.